# Not able to update identifierUris in Azure AD application's manifest file

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to follow this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/view-and-grant-products-from-a-service#step-1 on "Manage product entitlements from a service"

I created a new application in Azure AD (single-tenant application) and I reached the point where I need to set `"identifierUris"` in the manifest file with the following content:

```
"identifierUris" : [                                
        "https://onestore.microsoft.com",
        "https://onestore.microsoft.com/b2b/keys/create/collections",
        "https://onestore.microsoft.com/b2b/keys/create/purchase"
    ],
```

Whenever I do that, I get this error message:

```
Failed to update XXX application. Error detail: Application alias 'url' value is invalid. [Ja+Ze]
```

Any idea why I'm getting this error message? I tired to change some application settings but no luck so far

Comment: You can't use the `microsoft.com` domain, it is a reserved domain.
I had a look at the tutorial you're pointing at and it seems wrong. You can open an issue on github from the bottom on the documentation you were looking at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming *onestore.microsoft.com* is a sample custom tenant you might try with *{yourtenantname}.onmicrosoft.com*.